# c# percentage formatting with decimal places in specific cases

Tags: c#, formatting

In an app I'm building I need to format percentages the following way:

```
.00012 -> 0.01%
.0012 -> 0.12%
.012 -> 1.2%
.12 -> 12%
1.12 -> 112%
```

Percentages that are less than 1 should show 2 decimal places.  Anything that is 1 or great should show only 1 decimal place.

Currently I'm using the following 3 part format string *"0.0#%;(0.0#%);0%;"*, however I can't seem to get this to work the way I need, with different amount number of decimal places depending on the number.  I'd like to stick with the 3 part number format if at all possible, I don't want to have to do any multiplying by 100 if I don't have to.

Comment: This desired result is incorrect according to your specification: `.012 -> 1.2%`. It should have two decimal places since `0.012` is lower than 1.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I think he wants to mean the (left side value * 100) is lower than 1 not the (left side value).

Answer (score 4):

Use the [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to switch both cases with the `P`-format specifier.

```
var decimals = new List<decimal>() { 0.00012m, .0012m, .012m, .12m, 1.12m };
var result = decimals
    .Select(num => num >= 1 ? num.ToString("P1") : num.ToString("P2"));
```

The P- Format specifier which is for percents is exactly what you are after.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx):

> Number multiplied by 100 and displayed with a percent symbol.

Comment: Should change `N` to `P` which supports `%`

Comment: @CuongLe: Thanks, edited. I've just recognized that OP wants to multiply the number with 100 which is what the `P` format specifier does implicitely.

Comment: @CuongLe I couldn't believe there is a Vietnamese here with such a high reputation. :) -> Just be proud a little.

Comment: Unfortunately the "P" specifier strangely puts a space before the '%' sign. Obviously you can do `str.Replace(" %", "%")` but does anyone know a better way?

Comment: @ChrisNash: for me in germany there is no space, what's your current culture? So as a workaround you could use `num.ToString("P", new CultureInfo("de-DE"))`

Comment: @ChrisNash: another option is to provide the appropriate [`PercentPositivePattern`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.percentpositivepattern(v=vs.110).aspx) which is 1. Therefore you have to clone your current culture or `NumberFormatInfo`: `var nfi = (NumberFormatInfo)NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.Clone(); nfi.PercentPositivePattern = 1;`. Now you can pass this `NumberFormatInfo` instance to `ToString` as second parameter: `1.ToString("P", nfi)` will return `100%`(without space) everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

This should get you what you want:

```
Math.Round((percentage * 100), 2).ToString() + "%";
```

The code assumes your percentage is stored in the percentage variable